# Size of a Forest-Plot using Metafor or Meta packages

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot, metafor

I want to create a forest plot for a meta-analysis and I have the following problem with both metafor and the meta package. The forest plot is already so large with about 20 studies that it is no longer displayed properly in the plot window of Rstudio. Even saving it as a PNG doesn't help me because the plot is not displayed completely. What can I do?

Tried to save the plot as PNG, but that does not helped.

Comment: When exporting to PNG in Rstudio, try changing the width and height of the output. Alternatively, you could use `ggsave()` which also lets you control the dimensions in addition to the resolution of the output file.